# Use JOIN to multiply rows

Tags: postgresql, join, view

I'm writing this to share with this community the PRO and CONS of the solution that I have implemented as prototype in PostgreSQL Database.

Considering to have table (A) where for each row we have DateTime (h:00) and Value (int) as below:

```
10:00  50
11:00  40
12:00  85
```

I need to transform those value in table where all minutes are present (as example)

```
10:00  50
10:01  50
...
10:59  50
11:00  40
11:01  40
...
11:59  40
12:00  85
```

My idea is to right join table (A) with table (B) where all increments minutes (0-59) are present in order to develop a join and adding DateTime (h:00) with Table (B) minutes on other to get a VIEW with N x M all rows with values. Technically all is working but I would like to understand if this could be a solution considering also the rows trend of increasing.

Best Regards
Al

Answer (score 1):

You can use `generate_series()` for that:

```
select g.dt::time, t.*
from the_table t
  cross join generate_series(t.the_column, t.the_column + interval '1 hour', interval '1 minute') as g(dt)
order by g.dt;
```

Where `the_column` is the name of the column containing the "date time" (although your example seems to indicate that it only contains a `time`)

Comment: thank's for your contribution, do you think that in terms of performance your suggestion is  more efficient? DateTime also in resulting view (correct)